# ProtoGen.exe Enable service generation

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-csharp-port, protogen

From `sample.proto`

```
package Busy.Proto;
option optimize_for = SPEED;

message BusyRequest { required string message = 1;}
message BusyResponse {required string message = 1;} 
service BusyService {rpc Send (BusyRequest) returns (BusyResponse);}
```

generating `.cs` file, via following command, in package manager console

```
ProtoGen.exe sample.proto -output_directory="C:\SomeDir"
```

Resulting `sample.cs` file

```
 // Generated by ProtoGen, Version=2.4.1.555, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=55f7125234beb589.  DO NOT EDIT!
 #pragma warning disable 1591, 0612, 3021
 #region Designer generated code

 using pb = global::Google.ProtocolBuffers;

 ...

  #region Services
  /*
  * Service generation is now disabled by default, use the following option to enable:
  * option (google.protobuf.csharp_file_options).service_generator_type = GENERIC;
  */
 #endregion

 ...
```

Tried

- run `ProtoGen.exe sample.proto -output_directory="C:\SomeDir" option (google.protobuf.csharp_file_options).service_generator_type = GENERIC;` in Package manager Console. Ends with error

> The term 'google.protobuf.csharp_file_options' is not recognized as the name ..

- add `option service_generator_type = GENERIC;` in `sample.proto`. Ends with error

> cannot resolve symbol

How enable `Services` generation ?

Answer (score 1):

With latest versions of protogen you can pass the services option in order to generate the services also:
`protogen --csharp_out=. --proto_path=. +services=true *.proto`

I tested with protobuf-net.Protogen --version 3.0.0-alpha.122 and it seems not to work with 2.3.17 (last stable version as of today)

Answer (score 0):

Found answer on discussion [here](https://github.com/jskeet/protobuf-csharp-port/issues/93)

```
ProtoGen.exe -service_generator_type=GENERIC sample.proto  -output_directory="someDIR"
```